# How to structure an LMS in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm getting ready to build a simple LMS on rails 5. The site will let users select a course and inside the course, there will be lessons including videos and text. I plan on using a scaffold to build the CRUD functionality for the individual lessons.However, I'm not sure how to set up the site so I can create a new course on the front-end then add lessons to the course. I'm assuming the course model would use has_many with regards to lessons. Any suggestions about how to connect the courses and lessons would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the lessons reusable in multiple courses?  Then it has to be a HABTM (or HMT) relationship between courses and lessons... lessons can belong to many courses and courses can have many lessons.  this means you'll need a join table that connects the two records... a course_lesson join table will belong to a course and belong to a lesson.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I plan on having the lessons belong to only one course.

Comment: Ok, look at the `cocoon` gem to see how you can add nested lesson record forms within a course record form. And yes, lesson records should have a `course_id` and lesson class needs `belongs_to :course` and course class needs `has_many :lessons` and `accept_nested_attributes_for :lessons`

Comment: awesome I'll check out  `cocoon` thanks again for your help